# Creating a conditional loop with outputs

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

Mad Libs are activities that have a person provide various words, which are then used to complete a short story in unexpected (and hopefully funny) ways.

Write a program that takes a string and integer as input, and outputs a sentence using those items as below. The program repeats until the input string is quit.

Ex: If the input is:

apples 5
shoes 2
quit 0
the output is:

Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.
Note: This is a lab from a previous chapter that now requires the use of a loop.

my code:

```
user_text = input().split()
word = (user_text[0])
number = (user_text[1])

if word != 'quit':
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number, word))
    user_text= input()
```

outputs: Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.

Comment: Hi there. Can you specify what you want? It seem like you are copy paste a question from textbook here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping, so your program will only ask for input once, and end. If you want to keep inputting data, and printing new words, you should do the following:

```
word = ""

while True:
    user_text = input().split()
    word = (user_text[0])
    if word == 'quit':
        break
        
    number = (user_text[1])
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number, word))
```

As you can see by the code, while the user doesn't input the word quit, the program will ask for a new input, and print a new sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I try to use the code, it is still outputing all of the inputs even if the word quit is inputted.

Comment: I see what you mean. Check my updated answer, it should have solved your problem. If it's what you needed, mark it as correct! @DanielGardner

Answer (score 0):

Here is another very similar approach to this lab. Some school professors disapprove of using the while True: approach due to infinite loops, so here is a way around it.

```
user_input = input().split()
word = user_input[0]
number = user_input[1]

while (word != "quit"):
    print("Eating {0} {1} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(number, word))
    user_input = input().split()
    word = user_input[0]
    number = user_input[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept John B. used earlier in the thread gave me some inspiration and my code ended up somewhat similar. This code will only work for the lab or code with a similar concept if quit is never inputted there will be an error.

```
word_num = input().split( ) #first get the input and split it into 2 
word = word_num[0] # the word always comes first according to the lab
num = word_num[1] # then number

while word != "quit": # to get full marks do not loop if input is quit
    print("Eating", (num), (word), "a day keeps you happy and healthy.") # didn't use f'string contrary to other threads
    word_num = input().split( ) # this step ensures the program is looping
    word = word_num[0] #gets word again and will loop until word == "quit"
    num = word_num[1] # gets num and loops
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the code, for it to loop the question and end the program if the input is 'quit 0' write the following:

```
while True:
    user_input = input().split()
    if user_input[0] == "quit":
        break

    word = user_input[0]
    number = int(user_input[1])

    sentence = f"{number} {word}"

    print(f"Eating {sentence} a day keeps the doctor away.")
```